Who are these Korean actors, and actress, at 2023 Toronto International Film Festival?
I took pictures with these Korean actors and actress taken at 2023 TIFF (Toronto International Film Festival). But I forgot their names. Who are they? I edited myself out.




The upcoming film's stars Seo In Guk, Jang Dong Yoon, and Jung So Min joined director Kim Hong Sun ('Traffickers,' 'The Con Artists,' 'Metamorphosis') at the premiere screening, which was held at the Royal Alexandra Theatre, a massive 1,071-seat theater that serves as a main venue for the film festival.

Project Wolf Hunting's cast and director attend film's world premiere at 2022 Toronto International Film Festival (TIFF)


thanks. how did you recognize them?

@user16249 - I cheated and used a face recognition tool to identify the woman. The fact that she seems to have raided her hotel bathroom for jacket accessories made it very easy to find pictures of her at TIFF.
